# Getting Connection time out error in Heroku connecting to RDS MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, heroku

I am trying to connect to amazon RDS MySQL from Heroku using CodeIgniter PHP framework version 3. I followed all the steps listed in [Heroku documentation about Amazon RDS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#authorizing-access-to-rds-instance) but can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Here are my CodeIgniter database settings:

```
$db['rds'] = array(
  'dsn' => '',
  'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
  'dbprefix' => '',
  'pconnect' => FALSE,
  'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
  'cache_on' => FALSE,
  'cachedir' => '',
  'char_set' => 'utf8',
  'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
  'swap_pre' => '',
  'compress' => FALSE,
  'stricton' => FALSE,
  'failover' => array(),
  'save_queries' => TRUE,
  'port' => 3306,
  'encrypt' => [
    'ssl_ca' => APPPATH."../.config/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem",
    'ssl_verify' => TRUE
  ]
);
$db['rds']['hostname'] = getenv('RDS_DATABASE_HOSTNAME');
$db['rds']['username'] = getenv('RDS_DATABASE_USERNAME');
$db['rds']['password'] = getenv('RDS_DATABASE_PASSWORD');
$db['rds']['database'] = getenv('RDS_DATABASE_DBNAME');
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out /app/vendor/codeigniter/framework/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 201
```

Here is what I checked:

1. I checked in RDS security groups and CIDR/IP - Outbound 0.0.0.0/0 is there
2. I added a separate MySQL user with GRANT privileges SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE and REQUIRE SSL
3. Added the combined certificate file to project root directory `.config/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` and deployed on Heroku
4. On local machine the same code works fine
5. Tried restarting the RDS instance

Where else should I look if some setting is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CodeIgniter code needs to connect to your database, not the other way around. An outbound rule in your RDS security group won't help; you need an *inbound* rule (bold added):

> You must grant Heroku dynos access to your RDS instance. The recommended way to do this is to configure the RDS instance to only accept SSL-encrypted connections from authorized users and configure the security group for your instance to permit **ingress** from all IPs, eg `0.0.0.0/0`.

Since this effectively opens a hole in your firewall to the entire Internet it's very important to follow the rest of those instructions and only accept encrypted connections from authorized users.